# Create new object based on filtered keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

Suppose I have an array of strings that represent keys such as `['a', 'b', 'd']`, and an existing object such as...

```
const obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 4,
    e: 5
}
```

Is there a method of creating a new object that is a filtered version of `obj` based on the keys in the array such that...

```
const updated = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    d: 4
}
```

using the `Object.assign()` function?

I know it works with a function such as...

```
function createNew(o, keys) {
    const updated = {}

    Object.keys(o).forEach(k => {
      if (keys.includes(k)) updated[k] = o[k]
    })

    return updated
}
```

but I'm looking for a solution with `Object.assign()`

Comment: Why do you insist on using `Object.assign`?

Comment: Do you mean `Object.assign` in case `obj[key]` could be an object or an array and you don't want `obj[key]` and `result[key]` to share reference for the same thing?

Comment: Not using semicolons is a bad practice. It will eventually bite you, and the bug will be very hard to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 4,
    e: 5
};

const desiredKeys = ['a', 'c', 'd'];

const result = desiredKeys.reduce((acc, key) => {
    acc[key] = obj[key];
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```